# php for template files using another php configuration?

Tags: php, template-engine

i'm using php for over 10 years now and i sometimes (mainly in the early days) used it as a template engine, too. now i wonder if i can do that again, but i have one condition:

i need to load a very different php.ini then with the smallest possible amount of features for those template files. maybe a function like ini_set_all(file) could do it, but might be slow. using a different php ini for *.phpt or so should also not be that easy. any ideas on this?

and yes, i know and used engines like smarty, twig, etc., but the goal is to use plain php with the language elements it provides and maybe a bit more, but not using php to parse a template file to generate an automaton, array, php-file or whatever out of it.

update: my idea could be to switch a php template mode on/off with different ini settings and that may extend the following rfc: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nophptags

thanks for your ideas :)

Comment: probably you should put down some sample .ini config and some pseudo code of what you really want to achieve. Will help us to help you out :)

Comment: well, mainly all the stuff php ships by default just leaving few parts, see http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Comment: since all i understand is you are after a custom templating engine using php only... you might want to refer this post here: http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/08/building-a-custom-php-framework-with-a-custom-template-caching-engine-using-output-control-functions/ ... wrote it a few year back, but it focus primarily on how to write a custom templating engine in PHP only. Might just help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's your question exactly...?

Comment: its "can i use php as a template engine with most / all extensions and some functionalities turned off" and if so how to achieve it just for those template files to not touch the framework around them

Comment: @Hajo: I think you should edit your question and actually *ask* that. Also, you could expand on "how to achieve it just for those template files to not touch the framework around them", because I have no idea what that means.

Comment: the php configuration should be altered for those template files, maybe i need something like a "template mode" in php that can be turned on and off. i should suggest that as an rfc ;)

Comment: the only way I can think to implement it would be using php on the command line with a modified php.ini. I can't think of a way to temporarily switch to another php.ini and switch back after processing the template.

Comment: Yeah I'm not understanding why php.ini is coming into play at all, what difference does it make to disable a bunch of things?  Are you just trying to save memory by not loading a bunch of extensions?  If you use PHP and FastCGI, this isn't an issue as you can just have one instance of PHP running all the time that gets re-used and there is little overhead to parse each template.

Comment: i don't want to allow some php features in templates for security concerns. what i found so far is that my idea can be an extension to this rfc: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nophptags

Comment: I think it is more of a safety by disabling extensions/functions. essentially being able to disable specific functions that a template wouldn't necessarily need like file handling, database...etc. while still allowing basic functionality like if/then/else and loops.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn you nearly got it :)

Comment: @Hajo I see.  At the current time, the only solution I can think of then would be to process the templates using the PHP CLI which would allow you to specify a different `php.ini` file to use.  You can also run 2 separate versions of PHP on the same server and use different extensions (e.g. .php and .php5) but I still don't see a way that could help you.

Comment: i just try to use the programming language php for something it was initially made for. it was extended to an amount of functions that makes it impossible to still use it for that case without having to worry on what could happen due to it and i hoped there is a solution to still do it nevertheless. i might try to get that into that RFC ^^

Comment: The real question is why do you want that? The motivation is still obscure and makes it hard to find a possible solution except install PHP 1.x. Can you provide further information in the question?

Comment: the motivation is to use php for something it was initally made / designed for and i think that is completely mentioned in the question. the bounty is a last try to find ideas that keep me from writing the nophptags-rfc authors about this idea.

Answer (score 3):

This makes absolutely no sense.

Oh yes, and that's impossible too.

In fact, you have only 2 choices:

If templates intended to be edited by the site users who aren't allowed to the code - use some templating engine like Smarty or Twig (it will require some tweaking anyway, as these templates consists of 2 parts actually - the template part and template handler code part - it is still feasible).
Otherwise go for PHP with general settings, it will go very well.